# Rails has_many through polymorphic with namespaced models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

My classes and migrations are below. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, whether I've set up the associations wrong or I'm not using the correct attributes/methods to return the records I'm expecting. For example, how do I get a list of all members (`super_admin_users`, `admin_users` ***and*** `standard_users`) of an `account`? In the Rails console, if I try `Accounts::Account.first.users_account_members`, I get the following:

```
2.4.0 :003 > Accounts::Account.first.users_account_members
Accounts::Account Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "accounts_accounts".* FROM "accounts_accounts" ORDER BY "accounts_accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `users_account_members' for #<Accounts::Account:0x007fcb10cce7b8>
```

and if I try `Accounts::Account.first.users_super_admin_users`, I get the following:

```
2.4.0 :004 > Accounts::Account.first.users_super_admin_users
Accounts::Account Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "accounts_accounts".* FROM "accounts_accounts" ORDER BY "accounts_accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column accounts_account_memberships.accounts_account_type does not exist
```

where, by looking for `accounts_account_memberships.accounts_account_type`, it seems to be acting as though the `accounts_account` side of the association is polymorphic when only the users side is.

Additionally, how, inversely, do I get a list of all `accounts` a particular `super_admin_user` (or `admin_user`, or `standard_user`) is a member of?

Here are my classes with associations and their migrations:

**app/models/accounts/account.rb**

```
module Accounts
  class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

    self.table_name = 'accounts_accounts'

    belongs_to :users_account_owner, class_name: 'Users::SuperAdminUser', inverse_of: :accounts_owned_accounts
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users_account_owner

    has_many :accounts_account_memberships, class_name: 'Accounts::AccountMembership', as: :accounts_account, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users_super_admin_users, through: :accounts_account_memberships, source: :users_account_member, source_type: 'Users::SuperAdminUser'
    has_many :users_admin_users,       through: :accounts_account_memberships, source: :users_account_member, source_type: 'Users::AdminUser'
    has_many :users_standard_users,    through: :accounts_account_memberships, source: :users_account_member, source_type: 'Users::StandardUser'

  end
end
```

**app/models/users/super_admin_user.rb**

```
module Users
  class SuperAdminUser < ApplicationRecord

    self.table_name = 'users_super_admin_users'

    has_many :accounts_owned_accounts, class_name: 'Accounts::Account', inverse_of: :users_account_owner, foreign_key: :users_account_owner_id

    has_many :accounts_account_memberships, class_name: 'Accounts::AccountMembership', as: :users_account_member, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :accounts_accounts, through: :accounts_account_memberships, source: 'Accounts::Account'

  end
end
```

**app/models/users/admin_user.rb**

```
module Users
  class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord

    self.table_name = 'users_admin_users'

    has_many :accounts_account_memberships, class_name: 'Accounts::AccountMembership', as: :users_account_member, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :accounts_accounts, through: :accounts_account_memberships, source: 'Accounts::Account'

  end
end
```

**app/models/users/standard_user.rb**

```
module Users
  class StandardUser < ApplicationRecord

    self.table_name = 'users_standard_users'

    has_many :accounts_account_memberships, class_name: 'Accounts::AccountMembership', as: :users_account_member, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :accounts_accounts, through: :accounts_account_memberships, source: 'Accounts::Account'

  end
end
```

**app/models/accounts/account_membership.rb**

```
module Accounts
  class AccountMembership < ActiveRecord::Base

    self.table_name = 'accounts_account_memberships'

    belongs_to :accounts_account, class_name: 'Accounts::Account', inverse_of: :accounts_account_memberships
    belongs_to :users_account_member, polymorphic: true

  end
end
```

**db/migrate/20170203001000_create_users_super_admin_user.rb**

```
class CreateUsersSuperAdminUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users_super_admin_users do |t|

      t.string :email, index: { unique: true }
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :username, index: { unique: true }

      t.timestamps null: false

    end
  end
end
```

**db/migrate/20170203001100_create_users_admin_user.rb**

```
class CreateUsersAdminUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users_admin_users do |t|

      t.string :email, index: { unique: true }
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :username, index: { unique: true }

      t.timestamps null: false

    end
  end
end
```

**db/migrate/20170203001200_create_users_standard_user.rb**

```
class CreateUsersStandardUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users_standard_users do |t|

      t.string :email, index: { unique: true }
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :username, index: { unique: true }

      t.timestamps null: false

    end
  end
end
```

**db/migrate/20170204001000_create_accounts_account.rb**

```
class CreateAccountsAccount < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :accounts_accounts do |t|

      t.string :name, index: { unique: true }

      t.references :users_account_owner, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :users_super_admin_users }

      t.timestamps null: false

    end
  end
end
```

**db/migrate/20170204001100_create_accounts_account_membership.rb**

```
class CreateAccountsAccountMembership < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :accounts_account_memberships do |t|

      t.references :accounts_account, index: { name: 'index_accts_acct_mbrships_on_accts_acct_id' }
      t.references :users_account_member, polymorphic: true, index: { name: 'index_accts_acct_mbrships_on_users_acct_member_type_and_id' }

      t.timestamps null: false

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with such polymorphic associations you have to declare a type column in **AccountMembership** model.

Like this:

```
class AddAccountsAccountTypeToAccountsAccountMemberships < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :accounts_account_memberships, :accounts_account_type, :string
  end
end
```

If I understand you correctly, to get a list of all members you have to use `Accounts::Account.first.accounts_account_memberships` instead of  `Accounts::Account.first.users_account_members`

And to get a list of all `accounts` a particular `standard_user` you should call something like `Users::StandardUser.first.accounts_accounts`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I added the column you suggested and made a little bit of progress, i.e. I was no longer receiving the error about accounts_account_type, but it was still not returning the records. I also wasn't seeing how accounts_account_type was even needed, since the accounts_account side of the association is not polymorphic. I've suspected my problem had to do with the models being within namespaces and that does appear to have been the problem. See my solution, which now seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

So, the complication with this association is my use of namespaces, and the solution appears to be relatively simple -- primarily the addition of a `foreign_key:` option on the `accounts_account` side of the association.

I used this source as a starting point: http://joeswann.co.nz/rails-4-has_many-polymorphic-relationships, with `Article` adapted to each of the user types (`Users::SuperAdminUser`, `Users::AdminUser`, and `Users::StandardUser`), `Tag` adapted to `Accounts::Account` and `TagTarget` adapted to `Accounts::AccountMembership`. I then added in the `class_name:` and `foreign_key:` options where needed to accommodate the namespaces of the classes.

Additionally, I added an instance method `users_account_members` to the `Accounts::Account` class to enable retrieval of account members of all user types. I guess **I'm wondering what the point/benefit of a polymorphic relationship such as this is** if I can't retrieve all of the account members of all user types without the addition of this method. It seems I could achieve the same thing with separate `has_many` relationships between `Accounts::Account` and each of the user types.

The revised classes look as follows (there were no changes to the migrations):

```
module Accounts
  class Account < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :accounts_account_memberships, class_name: 'Accounts::AccountMembership', dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :accounts_account_id
    has_many :users_super_admin_users, through: :accounts_account_memberships, source: :users_account_member, source_type: "Users::SuperAdminUser"
    has_many :users_admin_users,       through: :accounts_account_memberships, source: :users_account_member, source_type: "Users::AdminUser"
    has_many :users_standard_users,    through: :accounts_account_memberships, source: :users_account_member, source_type: "Users::StandardUser"

    def users_account_members
      self.users_super_admin_users + self.users_admin_users + self.users_standard_users
    end
  end
end

module Accounts
  class AccountMembership < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :accounts_account, class_name: 'Accounts::Account'
    belongs_to :users_account_member, polymorphic: true
  end
end

module Users
  class SuperAdminUser < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :accounts_account_memberships, class_name: 'Accounts::AccountMembership', as: :users_account_member, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :accounts_accounts, through: :accounts_account_memberships, as: :users_account_member
  end
end

module Users
  class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :accounts_account_memberships, class_name: 'Accounts::AccountMembership', as: :users_account_member, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :accounts_accounts, through: :accounts_account_memberships, as: :users_account_member
  end
end

module Users
  class StandardUser < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :accounts_account_memberships, class_name: 'Accounts::AccountMembership', as: :users_account_member, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :accounts_accounts, through: :accounts_account_memberships, as: :users_account_member
  end
end
```

With these changes, the responses in the Rails console are now (Note: Database seed file appears below console output):

```
    2.4.0 :001 > Accounts::Account.first.users_account_owner
Accounts::Account Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "accounts_accounts".* FROM "accounts_accounts" ORDER BY "accounts_accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Users::SuperAdminUser Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users_super_admin_users".* FROM "users_super_admin_users" WHERE "users_super_admin_users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Users::SuperAdminUser id: 1, email: "garnold0@spotify.com", first_name: "Gregory", last_name: "Arnold", username: "garnold0", created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57"> 

    2.4.0 :002 > Users::SuperAdminUser.first.accounts_owned_accounts
Users::SuperAdminUser Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users_super_admin_users".* FROM "users_super_admin_users" ORDER BY "users_super_admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Accounts::Account Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "accounts_accounts".* FROM "accounts_accounts" WHERE "accounts_accounts"."users_account_owner_id" = $1  [["users_account_owner_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Accounts::Account id: 1, name: "Ooba", users_account_owner_id: 1, created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">]> 

    2.4.0 :003 > Accounts::Account.first.users_super_admin_users
Accounts::Account Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "accounts_accounts".* FROM "accounts_accounts" ORDER BY "accounts_accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Users::SuperAdminUser Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users_super_admin_users".* FROM "users_super_admin_users" INNER JOIN "accounts_account_memberships" ON "users_super_admin_users"."id" = "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_id" WHERE "accounts_account_memberships"."accounts_account_id" = $1 AND "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_type" = $2  [["accounts_account_id", 1], ["users_account_member_type", "Users::SuperAdminUser"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Users::SuperAdminUser id: 1, email: "garnold0@spotify.com", first_name: "Gregory", last_name: "Arnold", username: "garnold0", created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">, #<Users::SuperAdminUser id: 6, email: "ncruz5@huffingtonpost.com", first_name: "Nicole", last_name: "Cruz", username: "ncruz5", created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">]> 

    2.4.0 :004 > Accounts::Account.first.users_admin_users
Accounts::Account Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "accounts_accounts".* FROM "accounts_accounts" ORDER BY "accounts_accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Users::AdminUser Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users_admin_users".* FROM "users_admin_users" INNER JOIN "accounts_account_memberships" ON "users_admin_users"."id" = "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_id" WHERE "accounts_account_memberships"."accounts_account_id" = $1 AND "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_type" = $2  [["accounts_account_id", 1], ["users_account_member_type", "Users::AdminUser"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Users::AdminUser id: 4, email: "hlaned@whitehouse.gov", first_name: "Henry", last_name: "Lane", username: "hlaned", created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">, #<Users::AdminUser id: 9, email: "rharveyi@tripadvisor.com", first_name: "Raymond", last_name: "Harvey", username: "rharveyi", created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">]> 

    2.4.0 :005 > Accounts::Account.first.users_standard_users
Accounts::Account Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "accounts_accounts".* FROM "accounts_accounts" ORDER BY "accounts_accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Users::StandardUser Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users_standard_users".* FROM "users_standard_users" INNER JOIN "accounts_account_memberships" ON "users_standard_users"."id" = "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_id" WHERE "accounts_account_memberships"."accounts_account_id" = $1 AND "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_type" = $2  [["accounts_account_id", 1], ["users_account_member_type", "Users::StandardUser"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Users::StandardUser id: 2, email: "ghamiltonl@sciencedirect.com", first_name: "Gary", last_name: "Hamilton", username: "ghamiltonl", created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">, #<Users::StandardUser id: 7, email: "jkellyq@alexa.com", first_name: "Jonathan", last_name: "Kelly", username: "jkellyq", created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">]> 

    2.4.0 :006 > Accounts::Account.first.users_account_members
Accounts::Account Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "accounts_accounts".* FROM "accounts_accounts" ORDER BY "accounts_accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Users::SuperAdminUser Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users_super_admin_users".* FROM "users_super_admin_users" INNER JOIN "accounts_account_memberships" ON "users_super_admin_users"."id" = "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_id" WHERE "accounts_account_memberships"."accounts_account_id" = $1 AND "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_type" = $2  [["accounts_account_id", 1], ["users_account_member_type", "Users::SuperAdminUser"]]
Users::AdminUser Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users_admin_users".* FROM "users_admin_users" INNER JOIN "accounts_account_memberships" ON "users_admin_users"."id" = "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_id" WHERE "accounts_account_memberships"."accounts_account_id" = $1 AND "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_type" = $2  [["accounts_account_id", 1], ["users_account_member_type", "Users::AdminUser"]]
Users::StandardUser Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users_standard_users".* FROM "users_standard_users" INNER JOIN "accounts_account_memberships" ON "users_standard_users"."id" = "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_id" WHERE "accounts_account_memberships"."accounts_account_id" = $1 AND "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_type" = $2  [["accounts_account_id", 1], ["users_account_member_type", "Users::StandardUser"]]
=> [#<Users::SuperAdminUser id: 1, email: "garnold0@spotify.com", first_name: "Gregory", last_name: "Arnold", username: "garnold0", created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">, #<Users::SuperAdminUser id: 6, email: "ncruz5@huffingtonpost.com", first_name: "Nicole", last_name: "Cruz", username: "ncruz5", created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">, #<Users::AdminUser id: 4, email: "hlaned@whitehouse.gov", first_name: "Henry", last_name: "Lane", username: "hlaned", created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">, #<Users::AdminUser id: 9, email: "rharveyi@tripadvisor.com", first_name: "Raymond", last_name: "Harvey", username: "rharveyi", created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">, #<Users::StandardUser id: 2, email: "ghamiltonl@sciencedirect.com", first_name: "Gary", last_name: "Hamilton", username: "ghamiltonl", created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">, #<Users::StandardUser id: 7, email: "jkellyq@alexa.com", first_name: "Jonathan", last_name: "Kelly", username: "jkellyq", created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">] 

    2.4.0 :007 > Users::SuperAdminUser.first.accounts_accounts
Users::SuperAdminUser Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users_super_admin_users".* FROM "users_super_admin_users" ORDER BY "users_super_admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Accounts::Account Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "accounts_accounts".* FROM "accounts_accounts" INNER JOIN "accounts_account_memberships" ON "accounts_accounts"."id" = "accounts_account_memberships"."accounts_account_id" WHERE "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_id" = $1 AND "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_type" = $2  [["users_account_member_id", 1], ["users_account_member_type", "Users::SuperAdminUser"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Accounts::Account id: 1, name: "Ooba", users_account_owner_id: 1, created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">]> 

    2.4.0 :008 > Users::SuperAdminUser.second.accounts_accounts
Users::SuperAdminUser Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users_super_admin_users".* FROM "users_super_admin_users" ORDER BY "users_super_admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 1], ["OFFSET", 1]]
Accounts::Account Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "accounts_accounts".* FROM "accounts_accounts" INNER JOIN "accounts_account_memberships" ON "accounts_accounts"."id" = "accounts_account_memberships"."accounts_account_id" WHERE "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_id" = $1 AND "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_type" = $2  [["users_account_member_id", 2], ["users_account_member_type", "Users::SuperAdminUser"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Accounts::Account id: 4, name: "Brainsphere", users_account_owner_id: 4, created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">]> 

    2.4.0 :009 > Users::AdminUser.first.accounts_accounts
Users::AdminUser Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users_admin_users".* FROM "users_admin_users" ORDER BY "users_admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Accounts::Account Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "accounts_accounts".* FROM "accounts_accounts" INNER JOIN "accounts_account_memberships" ON "accounts_accounts"."id" = "accounts_account_memberships"."accounts_account_id" WHERE "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_id" = $1 AND "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_type" = $2  [["users_account_member_id", 1], ["users_account_member_type", "Users::AdminUser"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Accounts::Account id: 2, name: "Avamba", users_account_owner_id: 2, created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">]> 

    2.4.0 :010 > Users::AdminUser.second.accounts_accounts
Users::AdminUser Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users_admin_users".* FROM "users_admin_users" ORDER BY "users_admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 1], ["OFFSET", 1]]
Accounts::Account Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "accounts_accounts".* FROM "accounts_accounts" INNER JOIN "accounts_account_memberships" ON "accounts_accounts"."id" = "accounts_account_memberships"."accounts_account_id" WHERE "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_id" = $1 AND "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_type" = $2  [["users_account_member_id", 2], ["users_account_member_type", "Users::AdminUser"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Accounts::Account id: 5, name: "Wordtune", users_account_owner_id: 5, created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">]> 

    2.4.0 :011 > Users::StandardUser.first.accounts_accounts
Users::StandardUser Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users_standard_users".* FROM "users_standard_users" ORDER BY "users_standard_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Accounts::Account Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "accounts_accounts".* FROM "accounts_accounts" INNER JOIN "accounts_account_memberships" ON "accounts_accounts"."id" = "accounts_account_memberships"."accounts_account_id" WHERE "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_id" = $1 AND "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_type" = $2  [["users_account_member_id", 1], ["users_account_member_type", "Users::StandardUser"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Accounts::Account id: 3, name: "Linktype", users_account_owner_id: 3, created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">]> 

    2.4.0 :012 > Users::StandardUser.second.accounts_accounts
Users::StandardUser Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users_standard_users".* FROM "users_standard_users" ORDER BY "users_standard_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 1], ["OFFSET", 1]]
Accounts::Account Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "accounts_accounts".* FROM "accounts_accounts" INNER JOIN "accounts_account_memberships" ON "accounts_accounts"."id" = "accounts_account_memberships"."accounts_account_id" WHERE "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_id" = $1 AND "accounts_account_memberships"."users_account_member_type" = $2  [["users_account_member_id", 2], ["users_account_member_type", "Users::StandardUser"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Accounts::Account id: 1, name: "Ooba", users_account_owner_id: 1, created_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57", updated_at: "2017-02-11 21:01:57">]>
```

**db/seeds.rb**

```
Users::SuperAdminUser.create(email: 'garnold0@spotify.com',      first_name: 'Gregory', last_name: 'Arnold',   username: 'garnold0')
Users::SuperAdminUser.create(email: 'lsanders1@time.com',        first_name: 'Lisa',    last_name: 'Sanders',  username: 'lsanders1')
Users::SuperAdminUser.create(email: 'ssanders2@ucsd.edu',        first_name: 'Scott',   last_name: 'Sanders',  username: 'ssanders2')
Users::SuperAdminUser.create(email: 'aroberts3@g.co',            first_name: 'Anthony', last_name: 'Roberts',  username: 'aroberts3')
Users::SuperAdminUser.create(email: 'probinson4@bandcamp.com',   first_name: 'Paula',   last_name: 'Robinson', username: 'probinson4')
Users::SuperAdminUser.create(email: 'ncruz5@huffingtonpost.com', first_name: 'Nicole',  last_name: 'Cruz',     username: 'ncruz5')
Users::SuperAdminUser.create(email: 'gandrews6@cyberchimps.com', first_name: 'George',  last_name: 'Andrews',  username: 'gandrews6')
Users::SuperAdminUser.create(email: 'nwilson7@deviantart.com',   first_name: 'Nicole',  last_name: 'Wilson',   username: 'nwilson7')
Users::SuperAdminUser.create(email: 'aedwards8@qq.com',          first_name: 'Anne',    last_name: 'Edwards',  username: 'aedwards8')
Users::SuperAdminUser.create(email: 'rdavis9@geocities.jp',      first_name: 'Ronald',  last_name: 'Davis',    username: 'rdavis9')

Users::AdminUser.create(email: 'lhawkinsa@icio.us',            first_name: 'Lisa',    last_name: 'Hawkins',  username: 'lhawkinsa')
Users::AdminUser.create(email: 'htaylorb@imdb.com',            first_name: 'Helen',   last_name: 'Taylor',   username: 'htaylorb')
Users::AdminUser.create(email: 'gtaylorc@unblog.fr',           first_name: 'Gregory', last_name: 'Taylor',   username: 'gtaylorc')
Users::AdminUser.create(email: 'hlaned@whitehouse.gov',        first_name: 'Henry',   last_name: 'Lane',     username: 'hlaned')
Users::AdminUser.create(email: 'hphillipse@howstuffworks.com', first_name: 'Harry',   last_name: 'Phillips', username: 'hphillipse')
Users::AdminUser.create(email: 'jgonzalesf@com.com',           first_name: 'Jeffrey', last_name: 'Gonzales', username: 'jgonzalesf')
Users::AdminUser.create(email: 'ljamesg@sfgate.com',           first_name: 'Lori',    last_name: 'James',    username: 'ljamesg')
Users::AdminUser.create(email: 'rhillh@gnu.org',               first_name: 'Roger',   last_name: 'Hill',     username: 'rhillh')
Users::AdminUser.create(email: 'rharveyi@tripadvisor.com',     first_name: 'Raymond', last_name: 'Harvey',   username: 'rharveyi')
Users::AdminUser.create(email: 'sperryj@mit.edu',              first_name: 'Stephen', last_name: 'Perry',    username: 'sperryj')

Users::StandardUser.create(email: 'mblackk@prnewswire.com',       first_name: 'Michelle',   last_name: 'Black',     username: 'mblackk')
Users::StandardUser.create(email: 'ghamiltonl@sciencedirect.com', first_name: 'Gary',       last_name: 'Hamilton',  username: 'ghamiltonl')
Users::StandardUser.create(email: 'cgraym@about.com',             first_name: 'Chris',      last_name: 'Gray',      username: 'cgraym')
Users::StandardUser.create(email: 'jbradleyn@wikispaces.com',     first_name: 'Jacqueline', last_name: 'Bradley',   username: 'jbradleyn')
Users::StandardUser.create(email: 'jpayneo@netscape.com',         first_name: 'Joseph',     last_name: 'Payne',     username: 'jpayneo')
Users::StandardUser.create(email: 'drodriguezp@apache.org',       first_name: 'Debra',      last_name: 'Rodriguez', username: 'drodriguezp')
Users::StandardUser.create(email: 'jkellyq@alexa.com',            first_name: 'Jonathan',   last_name: 'Kelly',     username: 'jkellyq')
Users::StandardUser.create(email: 'creynoldsr@wired.com',         first_name: 'Cheryl',     last_name: 'Reynolds',  username: 'creynoldsr')
Users::StandardUser.create(email: 'kbarness@pbs.org',             first_name: 'Kathleen',   last_name: 'Barnes',    username: 'kbarness')
Users::StandardUser.create(email: 'ahansent@chron.com',           first_name: 'Annie',      last_name: 'Hansen',    username: 'ahansent')

Accounts::Account.create(name: 'Ooba',        users_account_owner_id: 1)
Accounts::Account.create(name: 'Avamba',      users_account_owner_id: 2)
Accounts::Account.create(name: 'Linktype',    users_account_owner_id: 3)
Accounts::Account.create(name: 'Brainsphere', users_account_owner_id: 4)
Accounts::Account.create(name: 'Wordtune',    users_account_owner_id: 5)

Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 1, users_account_member_type: 'Users::SuperAdminUser', users_account_member_id: 1)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 2, users_account_member_type: 'Users::AdminUser',      users_account_member_id: 1)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 3, users_account_member_type: 'Users::StandardUser',   users_account_member_id: 1)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 4, users_account_member_type: 'Users::SuperAdminUser', users_account_member_id: 2)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 5, users_account_member_type: 'Users::AdminUser',      users_account_member_id: 2)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 1, users_account_member_type: 'Users::StandardUser',   users_account_member_id: 2)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 2, users_account_member_type: 'Users::SuperAdminUser', users_account_member_id: 3)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 3, users_account_member_type: 'Users::AdminUser',      users_account_member_id: 3)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 4, users_account_member_type: 'Users::StandardUser',   users_account_member_id: 3)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 5, users_account_member_type: 'Users::SuperAdminUser', users_account_member_id: 4)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 1, users_account_member_type: 'Users::AdminUser',      users_account_member_id: 4)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 2, users_account_member_type: 'Users::StandardUser',   users_account_member_id: 4)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 3, users_account_member_type: 'Users::SuperAdminUser', users_account_member_id: 5)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 4, users_account_member_type: 'Users::AdminUser',      users_account_member_id: 5)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 5, users_account_member_type: 'Users::StandardUser',   users_account_member_id: 5)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 1, users_account_member_type: 'Users::SuperAdminUser', users_account_member_id: 6)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 2, users_account_member_type: 'Users::AdminUser',      users_account_member_id: 6)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 3, users_account_member_type: 'Users::StandardUser',   users_account_member_id: 6)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 4, users_account_member_type: 'Users::SuperAdminUser', users_account_member_id: 7)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 5, users_account_member_type: 'Users::AdminUser',      users_account_member_id: 7)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 1, users_account_member_type: 'Users::StandardUser',   users_account_member_id: 7)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 2, users_account_member_type: 'Users::SuperAdminUser', users_account_member_id: 8)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 3, users_account_member_type: 'Users::AdminUser',      users_account_member_id: 8)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 4, users_account_member_type: 'Users::StandardUser',   users_account_member_id: 8)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 5, users_account_member_type: 'Users::SuperAdminUser', users_account_member_id: 9)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 1, users_account_member_type: 'Users::AdminUser',      users_account_member_id: 9)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 2, users_account_member_type: 'Users::StandardUser',   users_account_member_id: 9)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 3, users_account_member_type: 'Users::SuperAdminUser', users_account_member_id: 10)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 4, users_account_member_type: 'Users::AdminUser',      users_account_member_id: 10)
Accounts::AccountMembership.create(accounts_account_id: 5, users_account_member_type: 'Users::StandardUser',   users_account_member_id: 10)
```